# Как изменить название пункта меню и иконку в админ-панели Wordpress

Tags: wordpress-плагины

Имеется сайт на вордпресс, уведомления об заполнении формы обратной связи реализованы через Contact Form 7 и Flamingo. Собственно вопрос в том, можно ли переименовать пункт "Flamingo" и заменить иконку? Хочется дать интуитивно понятное для пользователя название.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Возьмите плагин, чтобы не заморачиваться.
https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/